# Date filtering and populating to another to another column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataset like this below with two date columns.

```
DATE_LOCAL_1400           DATE_LOCAL_3000               
                        10.02.2017 12:00:00             
10.02.2017 12:00:00                                     
10.02.2017 12:00:00     11.02.2017 12:00:00             
10.02.2017 12:00:00     12.02.2017 12:00:00            
13.02.2017 12:00:00
```

I want to create new column called final date using below the calcualtion

1.If  data_local_3000 is present populate that value to final date else populate date_local_1400

```
DATE_LOCAL_1400           DATE_LOCAL_3000               Final Date
                        10.02.2017 12:00:00             10.02.2017 12:00:00
10.02.2017 12:00:00                                     10.02.2017 12:00:00
10.02.2017 12:00:00     11.02.2017 12:00:00             11.02.2017 12:00:00
10.02.2017 12:00:00     12.02.2017 12:00:00             12.02.2017 12:00:00
13.02.2017 12:00:00                                     13.02.2017 12:00:00
```

How to do this in python.

Answer (score 0):

use np.select:

```
df['Final Date'] = np.select(df['DATE_LOCAL_3000'].isna(), # condition
                             df['DATE_LOCAL_1400'], # choice
                             df['DATE_LOCAL_3000']) # default value
```

Answer (score 0):

use apply with axis=1 or axis='columns'.

```
df["Final Date"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["DATE_LOCAL_3000"] if x["DATE_LOCAL_3000"] else x["DATE_LOCAL_1400"], axis=1)
```